# Pluck childrens child only in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to **select** `brand` `name` only from `$collect`, what can I do to achieve that?

Current:

```
$collect = collect([
    0 => [
        ['name' => 'iPhone 6S', 'brand' => ['name' => 'Apple', 'type' => 'brand', 'id' => 1]],
    ],
    1 => [
        ['name' => 'Galaxy S7', 'brand' => ['name' => 'Samsung', 'type' => 'brand', 'id' => 2]],
    ],
]);
```

Expected result:

```
$collect = collect([
    0 => [
        ['name' => 'iPhone 6S', 'brand' => ['name' => 'Apple']],
    ],
    1 => [
        ['name' => 'Galaxy S7', 'brand' => ['name' => 'Samsung']],
    ],
]);
```

## EDIT

I tried using map() and each() collections provided by laravel, but none of them help.

## EDIT (ROSS)

This worked:

```
  $collect->transform(function ($item) {
    $itemData = collect($item);
      return $itemData->transform(function ($item, $key) {
        if($key == 'brand') {
          $item = array_only($item, 'name');
        }
        return $item;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Back at it, huh? lol May I ask, why do you need to select certain data? Dropdowns?

Comment: @MikeBarwick this question is different now. It's not dropdowns, but I am trying to not expose the data over my API.

Comment: In that case, just `foreach`. It's safest, cleanest, and readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$collect->transform(function ($item) {
    return collect($item)->transform(function ($item) {
        $item['brand'] = array_only($item['brand'], 'name');
        return $item;
    })->toArray();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks to be good code, i am getting this error: `array_intersect_key(): Argument #1 is not an array`

Comment: @PHPLover What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using, what I've noticed is that inside transform you are looping through each key of brand

Comment: Probably, an IF statement is needed to check the key.

Comment: @PHPLover Cool. In that case, it looks like you have one less level of your array in your code compared to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($collect as $key => $row) {
    $collect[$key]['brand'] = ['name' => $collect[$key]['brand']['name']];
}
```

Comment: What do You mean by "Select"?

Comment: This works as expected, thank you. Do you know a way to transform this using map collection from laravel?

Comment: Best and cleanest route, is this one. No need for map. +1

Comment: I saw somewhere on laravel official page they did: $collect->*->brand->name; but can not find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do something like this using `Collection` class, then you can use `map` function:

```
// Instantiate the collection
$collect = collect($collect);

$transformedArray = $collect->map(function($item) { 
  unset($item[0]['brand']['type']); 
  unset($item[0]['brand']['id']); 
  return $item; 
})
```

**OR**

If you insist not using `unset`,

```
$collect->map(function($item) { 


    $temp = [];

    $temp[] = ['name' => $item[0]['name'],
        'brand' => ['name' => $item[0]['brand']['name']]
    ];
    return $temp; 


})
```

In this use case, `map` is more appropriate since we are basically just reformatting the structure

Comment: I need to find a way to select not to remove, because new fields may appear and my columns will be exposed, which is not futureproof.

Comment: @PHPLover Collection won't change the original data. You can try and check the value of `$collect` should be still the old one

Comment: Updated as your question

Comment: What if there is more properties then name inside the collect, to keep them I will have to write them all here?

Comment: @PHPLover In that case, first method works perfectly fine. Collection is an immutable object even though I used unset it should not modify the original item